# Match two profiles in Django framework

Tags: python, django, forms, algorithm, django-models

I made a web app which consists of two categories(let's say A and B) of users and there is a common board upon which they can both post something. Now if a person(John) from category A is suggested that his best match is person(wick) from category B by a django card, how can I make something that notifies both of them.

Suppose JOHN like what WICK is offering and there is a book button he sees on WICK's card(mini profile). Now I want to notify Wick that JOHN is interested in you  when JOHN clicks on the Book button.

example data

Manufacturer

```
M_ID   From  To  M_Type    T_Type  T_Length T_Weight #Trucks 
JOHN   A     B   Boxes     Open    12-Tyre  22       3       
BLAKE  C     D   Cylinders Trailer HIGH     23       2       
GREG   G     H   Scrap     Open    14-Tyre  25       5
```

Transporter

```
T_ID  From To T_Type  T_Length T_Weight #Trucks  Price
WICK  A    B  Open    12-Tyre  22       5        1500
PATEL G    H  Open    14-Tyre  25       10       1200   
NICK  A    B  Open    12-Tyre  22       7        1900
```

The algo returns data in this format

```
Manufacturer   Best Match   Second Best
JOHN           WICK         NICK
GREG           PATEL         -
```

I can show JOHN that his best matches are WICK and NICK( and when he clicks on them their mini profile will be shown to him with a BOOK option but what do I do next to make something happen(alert WICK/NICK) when he clicks on the book button??

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather broad question, but here goes.

JOHN clicks, and the processing of the request will either do something immediately (such as sending an e-mail to NICK), or it will store something in the database which will be brought to NICK's attention the next time NICK interacts with the application.
Perhaps a notifications table with foreign keys for JOHN (notifier), NICK (notifiee --yuk ), and associated data.

Something like this latter is how I will see at the top of the stackoverflow page, when you up-vote this post or add a comment. If I don't come back to stackoverflow for a month, I'll see it then, or you might include an expiry date with what you store so that after that period of time has passed, the notification will be considered stale and deleted on the fly without NICK ever becoming aware of it.

I expect you can find something that somebody else has written to implement most of this, somewhere out there. Probably, a form of middleware, if it is to be checked on literally every interaction rather than just at log-in. Sorry, I can't offer any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't talk in SQL tables when in reality you work on Django ORM level of abstraction.

All you need is a ManyToMany field. You'll add that m2m field and show new ones to user offering was made for (maybe merge Manufacturer and Transporter to one Model (table) to not duplicate this functionality).

Instead of using auto m2m, I suggest you use [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to add extra field, such as Boolean `has_been_seen`. Or you can make a guess instance has been seen if user's `last_activity` is bigger than datetime that instance was created at.